# Uniform distribution transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf $f_X(x) = 6x-6x^2$ if $0<x<1$, and $0$ otherwise. Let $Y=3X^2-2X^3$. Show that is a uniform distribution $U(0,1)$.

My attempt:

Specifically, $X = g^{-1}(Y)$ is a well defined inverse on $(0,1)$. The Jacobian of this transformation is $\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|$ is what I am struggling to find. Can someone help me on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

$$y = g(x)$$
By using [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem),
$$\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)=\frac1{g'(x)}=\frac1{6x-6x^2},$$

hence $Y$ is uniform.

Comment: please can you explain what $g^{-1}(Y)$ would be? How do I find X in terms of Y?

Comment: hmmm... i didn't compute that. I used inverse function theorem which avoided computing that explicitly.